# DatePipe formatting not working on date in table

Tags: angular

I am developing a simple app in which I want to show some events in a table. Displaying the data works fine, except when I try to format the date, it doesn't show anymore.

I have tried importing the `Pipe` and `PipeTransform` from `"@angular/core"` and the `DatePipe` from `"@angular/common"`, this didn't change anything. Any kind of formatting, whether its the predefined formats like `"fullDate"`, or custom formatting like `"dd.MM.y"` will make the date not show up in the table.

These are the td tags in the table body, if I display the date like this without formatting, it shows up fine.

```
<tr *ngFor="let event of eventList" style="cursor:pointer;">
     <td (click)="onSelect(event.id)" style="padding-bottom: 1.3em">{{event.name}}</td>
     <td (click)="onSelect(event.id)">{{event.city}}</td>
     <td (click)="onSelect(event.id)">{{event.startTime}}</td>
     <td (click)="onSelect(event.id)">
         <mat-icon *ngIf="event.isConfirmed" style="padding-left: 23px">done</mat-icon>
         <mat-icon *ngIf="!event.isConfirmed" style="padding-left: 23px">clear</mat-icon>
     </td>
</tr>
```

This is how I tried formatting the date:

```
<td (click)="onSelect(event.id)">{{ event.startTime | date : "dd.MM.y" }}</td>
```

I am fairly new to Angular so feel free to point out mistakes. 
Am I missing import statements or is the styling of the other td tags messing up the date? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you should be able to  use it by importing `@angular/common` in your component module.

Comment: Please also show an example of what a date value specifically looks like in your case.

Comment: I am using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework so the dates are .NET Core DateTime values. When I display the date without formatting it looks like this: ```Fri Jul 12 2019 11:59:40 GMT+0200```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, I am using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework and apparently something is wrong with the localization. When I set the language to English (default) the formatted date shows up fine. I had it set to dutch for testing purposes and I spotted the console error `Missing locale data for the locale "nl".' for pipe 'DatePipe'` when trying the formatting.

Thanks for all the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Do ensure that you have imported `CommonModule` into the very same module.ts as your component.html that is using the date pipes.

sample.module.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

 .
 .
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    CommonModule,
  ],
  .
  .
})
```

I have made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-example-xmahyk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) for you, using the exact same date pipe you have used.

Comment: Thank you! My app.module.ts does import the ```CommonModule``` so that should not be the problem. I also tried import the CommonModule from ```@angular/common``` in my module.ts, this does not solve the problem however.

Comment: Hmm, I noticed that you mentioned that your date is in this format `Fri Jul 12 2019 11:59:40 GMT+0200`. Do you wanna try converting it to the JavaScript Date object before running in through the Date Pipe?